# Multiple application.yml not merged in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties, yaml

I have a module for database communication`(my-db-lib)`, and which is imported to spring boot based web application module`(my-web-app)`

I want to set configuration about db in `my-db-lib`, and set about web app in `my-web-app`

#### When I use yml file,

1. application.yml in `my-db-lib`

   `db:
     url: localhost`
2. application.yml in `my-web-app`

   `app: 
     message: hello`

When `my-web-app` runs, it can read only `app.message` not `db.url`

It seems that yml files are just replaced with one which has highest priority (when not use profiles)
Is it right? How can I achieve purpose?

Thanks,
And sorry for my poor English :D

Answer (score 2):

As a trick, I moved the other application.yml to the '/config' folder.

This should probably work.

```
my-db-lib/src/main/resources/config/application.yml
my-web-app/src/main/resources/application.yml
```

Perhaps you need to use a sufficiently high version of Spring Boot.

Note: Folders different from '/config', such as '/config/db', will not work.

Answer (score 1):

The `application.yml` in child module will be override by `application.yml` in parent module.

You can use this:

1. `application-my-db-lib.yml` for module `my-db-lib`
2. `application.yml` for module `my-web-app`

Comment: How will Spring Boot know to load the lib specific application-my-db-lib.yml? To my knowledge it only scans for application.yml and everything with a suffix has to be added via active profiles.