# Overriden application.yml in multi-module Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

There is a Spring Boot 2 app with such a structure:

```
parent-module
    module-1
        src
            main
                java
                resources
                - application.yml
    module-2
        src
            main
                java
                resources
                - application.yml
```

Also, module-1 depends on module-2, specified in pom.xml `dependencies` section.

The problem is that when I specify some properties in module-2's `application.yml` - they are not visible in main module-1's components (via `@Value` annotation).

As was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52925721/3482923) seems like module-1's `application.yml` overrides module-2's `application.yml`. There is a workaround - if I use name `application.yaml` in module-2 everything works fine, but I'm going to add more modules and, finally, it's dirty hack.

What I'm doing wrong? Should such an hierarchy of property files specified somehow?
I will be happy to provide more details if it's needed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot is a runtime framework. I understand that your modules are not spring-boot applications by themselves (you can't make a dependency on a spring boot application packaged with spring boot maven plugin, because it produces an artifact that is not really a JAR from the Java's standpoint although it does have *.jar extension).

If so, they're probably regular jars. So you should have a "special" module that assembles the application. This special module lists both 'module1' and 'module2' in `<dependency>` section and should contain a definition of `spring-boot-maven-plugin` in its `build` section (assuming you're using maven). But if so you shouldn't really have more than one application.yml - it will be misleading. Instead, put the `application.yml` to the `src/main/resources` of that "special" module.

If you really have to for whatever reason work with multiple `application.yaml` files, make sure you've read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33229793/how-to-add-multiple-application-properties-files-in-spring-boot/49799482)

Answer (score 2):

I know, this is already a well-aged post.

I just came accross the same issue and the best solution I found was to import the module-specific configurations with the `spring.config.import` directive as described [here](https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/config-file-processing-in-spring-boot-2-4).

In this case you still have your module specific configuration in property or yaml files within that specific module and do not have too much unwanted dependencies in your project setup.

Answer (score 0):

`application.yml` is, as the name indicates, an application-level file, not a module-level file.

It is the build script that assembles the final application, e.g. the `.war` file, that needs to include a `application.yml` file, if any.

If modules need properties, and cannot rely on the defaults, e.g. using the `:` syntax in `@Value("${prop.name:default}")`, they need to provide a module-level property file using `@PropertySource("classpath:/path/to/module-2.properties")`.

*Note:* By default, `@PropertySource` doesn't load YAML files (see [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml-shortcomings)), but Spring Boot can be enhanced to support it. See [@PropertySource with YAML Files in Spring Boot | Bealdung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml-propertysource).

---

**Alternative:** Have the application-level build script (the one building the `.war` file) merge multiple module-level build scripts into a unified `application.yml` file.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Could you please share an example of an alternative solution, regarding the merging of 'application.yml' files?

Comment: @DmitryAdonin Sorry, that's for you to code, and decide how they merge.